# Changing class of an element removes all its previous styles?

Tags: javascript, css

This is sort of a very basic question.

If is a `<div>` with `class="oldClass"`. 
If I change the class of that div to `class="newClass"` using JavaScript(using .className). will all its previous style go away? Or only style which is defined in both classes will be applied after applying `newClass`?

to elaborate my question more. if `oldClass` is

```
.oldClass
{
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:green;
}
```

and `newClass` is

```
.newClass{
    background-color:black;
}
```

After applying `newClass` using javascript (using .className) which styles will the element have?

***(Note- I tested this couple of times using different codes. got different results each time. That's why I am asking even tough its a very basic question)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only newClass  `background-color:black;` will be applied

Reply to your Comment: [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3PpaM/)

Comment: so div should only have black background? and not the red border?

Answer (score 0):

1. An element with a class of "oldClass" will have a 1px solid red border and a green background.
2. An element with a class of "newClass" will have a black background.
3. An element with a class of "oldClass" *and* "newClass" will have a 1px solid red border and either a green background or a black background depending on the order of those selectors in your CSS document.

Therefore, if you *remove* "oldClass" by setting the `className` to "newClass", the styles defined in your `.oldClass` selector will no longer be present on that element, but the `.newClass` selector styles will be present.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/y8K3u/1).

Answer (score 0):

At any moment, all the style rules that can match an element will be applied to it in a particular order*. If you replace class oldClass with newClass, the element will no longer have the oldClass class, so style rules specified for oldClass may no longer apply to it.

An element can have more than one class at a time. To set more than one class, simply separate them via space.

*) The order is a little more difficult to explain, but the very basics are:

1. `!important` values have the highest priority
2. properties set via style
3. rules with more id selectors (`#element`)
4. rules with more class and attribute selectors (`.class` and `[attr]`)
5. rules with more tagnames (`tag`)
6. rules last in the stylesheet

You can read more about specificity [here](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Example:

HTML

```
<div id="el" class="c1 c2 c3" style="color:green">I am text</div>
```

CSS:

```
#el { /* matches elements with id=el */
  color:red;
  background-color:blue;
}

.c1.c2 { /* matches elements with classes c1 and c2 */
  height:50px;
}

.c1,
.c2 { /* matches elements with class c1 and elements with class c2 */
  height:100px;
}

.c1 { /* matches elements with class c1 */
  color:grey;
  background-color:purple;
}

.extra { /* matches elements with class extra */
  width:50px;
}
```

In that example, the div will have the following styles:

- **color:green** (overrides other colors because it's set in style)
- **background-color:blue** (overrides purple because id is more specific than class)
- **height:50px** (overrides 100px because 2 classes in selector are more specific than one)

If you were to swap `c1` for `extra`, it will have the following styles:

- **color:green**
- **height:100px** (height:50px does not match because element doesn't have class c1)
- **width:50px** (matches because element has class extra)